# Put request to /api/controller/:id instead of /api/controller?id=:id

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm currently doing this:

```
[HttpPut]
public void Edit(int id, Model model)
{
    ...
}
```

Which gives me the endpoint `/api/controller?id=66` instead of what I want: `/api/controller/66`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get what you want -- `api/controller/66` on your `PUT` request, your HTTP verb attribute should be modified to `[HttpPut("{id}")]`

And the further reason why your `id` is obtained from the query string by default is that the parameter binding in the case of `PUT` request works in such a way that the primitive type is bound from request query string and the complex type from request body.

A brief of the parameter binding rules is listed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63254690/5253437) answer.